# How can I turn off animals in creative mode?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-worldedit

Is there a way to turn off animals in creative mode in minecraft? I have world edit installed.

Answer (score 3):

Set the game rule **doMobSpawning** to ***false***.

`/gamerule doMobSpawning false`

Answer (score 3):

You don't even need WorldEdit: just type `/gamerule doMobSpawning false`, and then type `kill @e` to kill everything that's alive. Once you respawn there will be no animals or mobs left.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the WorldGuard mob-spawning flag:

```
/region flag __global__ mob-spawning deny
```

<sub>Using: WorldEdit and MV 2.5 b641</sub>

Comment: requires worldguard and the region is `__global__`

Comment: What is mv? Where do I download it. Without it I get command not found.

Comment: @AriPorad You'll need WorldGuard for this, not Multiverse.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I was not playing on peaceful mode, when you do that, all the animals go away.

Comment: Um, animals still spawn on peaceful.  Only hostile mobs are removed...

Comment: @MBraedley, I don't know, but I am playing in creative mode, cheats enabled, peaceful, and not letting it get dark, and no animals.

Answer (score -2):

The following command stops spawning naturally:

```
/doMobSpawning false
```

Comment: Does that apply to animals as well, or just enemy mobs?